# Merging rows from .csv files with different lengths (python 3.x)

Tags: csv, python-3.x, merge

`File1:`

```
2015-01-01 07:00     1    1    1    1
2015-01-01 07:01     1    1    1
2015-01-01 07:02     1    1    1    1
```

`File2:`

```
2015-01-01 07:00     2    2 
2015-01-01 07:01     2    2
2015-01-01 07:02     2    2
```

I want to merge the files from `File2` into `File1` considering the Timestamp of each row. so I wrote a `dictionary`for `File1`and `File2` `dict1` and `dict2`with `k`= Timestamp and `v`= values.
my code looks like this:

```
merged_files = {d1k: d1v+File2Dic.get(d1k[:],[]) for d1k,d1v in File1Dic.items()}
```

that gets me an output:
`merged_files`:

```
2015-01-01 07:00     1    1    1    1    2    2
2015-01-01 07:01     1    1    1    2    2
2015-01-01 07:02     1    1    1    1    2    2
```

And I want:

```
2015-01-01 07:00     1    1    1    1    2    2
2015-01-01 07:01     1    1    1         2    2
2015-01-01 07:02     1    1    1    1    2    2
```

Any idea on how i can adjust the merge code to get to that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas function [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then fill `NaN` values with empty string.

You can write result to csv by function [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv).

Explaining, why in column 4 is `1.0` instead `1`:
Because `NaN` values are cast to float64. [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""2015-01-01 07:00;1;1;1;1
2015-01-01 07:01;1;1;1;
2015-01-01 07:02;1;1;1;1"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", header=None)
print df

temp1=u"""2015-01-01 07:00;2;2 
2015-01-01 07:01;2;2
2015-01-01 07:02;2;2"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), sep=";", header=None)
print df1

#merge by first column - by dates
result = pd.merge(df, df1, on=0)
#fill NaN values by empty string
result = result.fillna('')
print result
#                  0  1_x  2_x  3  4  1_y  2_y
#0  2015-01-01 07:00    1    1  1  1    2    2
#1  2015-01-01 07:01    1    1  1       2    2
#2  2015-01-01 07:02    1    1  1  1    2    2

print result.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
#2015-01-01 07:00,1,1,1,1.0,2,2
#2015-01-01 07:01,1,1,1,,2,2
#2015-01-01 07:02,1,1,1,1.0,2,2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ... what are `temp=u`and `temp1=u` ?

Comment: Instead `io.StringIO(temp)` you can use `file1.csv` and similar with `io.StringIO(temp1)`

Comment: o  I did not get that they where prints

Comment: if you have separator in csv tabulator, you can use `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\t", header=None)`

Comment: it helped me yes. missed to accepted button and was away the last days, sorry for the delay